# how can I count each csv's row count given the solution I have

Tags: c#, .net, csv, console-application

I have the following code which seperates my Records.CSV files to two different CSV files based on COMPID (-> a key given in a dictionary I created):
(the first 3 files): records(1) sepereated into two above(2) :

[image]

anyways, I need to count each csv individually(basically each file) for the number of rows and add it distinctly like the following:

[image]

and this is my function:

[image]

now my problem is, that I cant distinct each file to get its own length, as showed in red ( in the code ), the top line will be the same in each CSV.
how can I achieve two different lengths for two different files, given the solution I already have?
before u guys say, I know its not optimal, I add the first line with each iteration which is wrong, and its probably one of many mistakes I have rn,  but I just need a working solution for now.

edit ** code

```
   //Get values needed for the file's names
string chargeMonth = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMM");
var fileCreationDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
string fileCreationTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss");
string constVal = "MLL";
string fileType = "HIYUV-CHEVRA";

//Initiate variables
string[] values;
string header, sumRow;
string line, compId;
string inputFile = "records.CSV";

//Create a Dictionary that will have CompanyId as keys (for example 10, 1000)
Dictionary<string, System.IO.StreamWriter> outputFiles = new Dictionary<string, System.IO.StreamWriter>();
//Read from records.csv which is the complete datatable from database
using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("D:\\" + inputFile, Encoding.Default))
       {
           //header line ( columns )
           header = file.ReadLine();
           //As long as line isnt null
           while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
           {
               //Seperates with comma each value (total of 24 values-columns)
               values = line.Split(",".ToCharArray());
               //Gets company_Id
               compId = values[3];
               //Checks if Key doesnt contain CompanyId inside the dictionary
               if (!outputFiles.ContainsKey(compId))
               {
                   //This will be the created file's name
                   string outputFileName = constVal + "-" + fileType + "-" + (String.Format("{0:00000}", Int32.Parse(compId))) + "-" + chargeMonth + "-" + fileCreationDate + "-" + fileCreationTime + ".CSV";
                   //Adding keys/values to dictionary
                   outputFiles.Add(compId, new System.IO.StreamWriter("D:\\" + outputFileName));

                   //Getting number of lines ( records ) - execluding sumRow and Columns(headers)
                   //int rowNumberKey = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("d:/records.csv").Length - 2;

                   //Foreach compId key ( two keys overall/2csvs overall ) -> will add the following line
                   //outputFiles[compId].WriteLine((String.Format("{0:00000}", Int32.Parse(compId))) + "," + chargeMonth + "," + fileCreationDate + "," + fileCreationTime + (String.Format("{0:00000}", rowNumberKey)) + ".CSV");
                     outputFiles[compId].WriteLine(header);

                 }
                    //Will write the line where company_id is key inside the dictionary(outputFiles)
                    outputFiles[compId].WriteLine(line);
              }
            }
            //Iterating through each key which is now a file > and closing each
            foreach (System.IO.StreamWriter outputFile in outputFiles.Values)
            {
                outputFile.Close();
            }
      }
```

thanks!

Comment: can you paste the code into the question and format it with the "{}" button.

Comment: ye ofc will do .. thanks

Comment: its quite a complicated context, is it possible to create a much simpler example? You are reading data from somewhere (I don't think it matter where), so each line is an array of string? and then you want to count the distinct unique lines?

Comment: basically my task is export a database table inside a main csv file, and from there I have value(3rdcolumn) which is called 'Company_Id', I want to seperate the records of that main csv into different csvs based on that companyId( like all companyId -1 will go into csv1/companyid2 will go into csv2, and so on.., and create a unique header for each with a sum row on top(line1) that will include the Number of records that are in that csv:)) thx for ur help, if u have something more simple it will be amazing !

Comment: ok, so read all the data out into a big array of arrays (I'd probably use File.ReadAllLine()..then look at ToLookup(), where you can specify how to group the lines by CompanyId, then loop through the lookup and for each entry (group) create a distinct file)